# The set of surjective linear transformations is open

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The set of inyective linear transformation is open in $\mathcal{L}\left(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^n \right)$ and the set of surjective linear transformation is open in $\mathcal{L}\left(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^n \right)$.

- The set of inyective linear transformation is open in $\mathcal{L}\left(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^n \right)$.

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ a inyective aplication, then there is $\alpha >0$ such that $\left\| Tx \right\| > \alpha \left\|x \right\|$, now if $S:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is linear transformation and $\left\|S-T \right\|< \alpha $, let $a=\alpha-\left\|S-T \right\|>0$  then

\begin{eqnarray*}
 \alpha\left\| x\right\|&\leqslant& \left\| Tx\right\|  \\
  &\leqslant& \left\|Tx -Sx\right\| + \left\|Sx\right\| 
\end{eqnarray*}

Now $$a\left\| x\right\| \leqslant \left\| Sx\right\| $$ and $S$ is inyective.

-The set of surjective linear transformation is open in $\mathcal{L}\left(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^n \right)$.

If $m<n$ there arent the set of surjective linear transformation in $\mathcal{L}\left(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^n \right)$ is empty, then it is open.

If $m=n$  the set of surjective linear transformation in $\mathcal{L}\left(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^n \right)$ is equal to the set of inyective linear transformation in $\mathcal{L}\left(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^n \right)$, then its open.

I dont idea with $n<m$, Do you have any help with this part?

Comment: You could use $T$ is surjective if and only if its transpose $T^T$ is injective.

Comment: At a calculational level, if an $m \times n$ matrix is surjective i.e. has rank $m$, then there exists some selection of $m$ columns which span $\mathbb{R}^m$ and so the corresponding $m \times m$ submatrix has nonzero determinant; and the determinant of this submatrix is continuous in the entries of the original matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $T \in \mathcal L(\mathbb R^m,\mathbb R^n)$ is surjective.  Let $V \in \mathcal L(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^m)$ be a linear one-sided inverse, that is, $VT = I_m$.  Note $V \ne 0$.

Then for any $S \in \mathcal L(\mathbb R^m,\mathbb R^n)$ with $\|S\| < \frac12\|V\|^{-1}$, define
$$ W = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (VS)^n = I_m + VS + (VS)^2 + \cdots .$$
Show by direct calculation that the sum is Cauchy, and hence converges, and also show
$$(I_m-VS)W = W(I_m-VS) = I_m.$$
Then
$$ WV(T-S) = W(I_m - VS) = I_m ,$$
that is, $WV$ is a left inverse to $T-S$.

But I think it is easier to show using $T^t$ is injective.  (Note $\|T\| = \|T^t\|$ if you use the Euclidean norm.)

Comment: If $T$ is is surjective, then $T^t$ is inyective and there is $\epsilon$ such that $\left\|T^t-S \right\|<\epsilon$ then $S$ is inyective.
Now if $\left\|T-W \right\|<\epsilon$, then $\left\|T^t-W^t \right\|<\epsilon$ and $W^t$ is inyective and $W$ is sujerctive.

Is this your idea?

Comment: how do you conclude that S has left inverse?

Comment: I concluded $T-S$ had the left inverse.

Comment: If $\|T - W\| < \epsilon$, let $S = T - W$.  Then $\|S\| < \epsilon$.  So I conclude $T-S$ has a left inverse.  But $T-S = W$.  So $W$ has a left inverse.

Comment: Now if I understand, thank you. 
I think they are right inverse, but the idea does not change.

Comment: I think my terminology is standard: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_element

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112697/discussion-between-carlos-andres-henao-acevedo-and-stephen-montgomery-smith).